# How to divide a number into multiple parts so that the resulting sum is equal to the input?

Tags: c#

I am trying to divide a number into multiple parts so the sum of the part are equal to the input number.

If I have 3.99 and if I need to divide into two parts, the expected output is 2 and 1.99 (2+1.99=3.99)

And if I need to divide 3.99 into 3 parts, the expected output is 1.3, 1.3 and 1.39 (1.3+1.3+1.39=3.99)

I was able to output 2.99 and 1 for the first example and I was able to get 1.99, 1 and 1 for the second example. However, in both the cases results are very far from the expected output.

I need to split postal charges into separate line items. The result could be equally divided or unequally divided while making sure that the sum of the different parts is equal to the input number.

Here are some other examples:

```
3.99 divided in 3 parts: 1.33, 1.33, 1.33
3.98 divided in 3 parts: 1.33, 1.33, 1.32
3.97 divided in 3 parts: 1.32, 1.32, 1.33
3.96 divided in 3 parts: 1.32, 1.32, 1.32
3.95 divided in 3 parts: 1.32, 1.32, 1.31
```

Comment: I believe this is more a math problem than a coding problem
Why wouldnt you divide through the number of parts you like to have?
i.e.
3.99 / 2 = 1.995 (2x)
3.99 / 3 = 1.33 (3x)

Comment: Why wouldn't 3.99 divided into 3 parts be 1.33, 1.33, 1.33 instead?

Comment: *"But in both the cases result is very far from the expected output"* -- how did it vary? What did you try? What was the expected outcome? [What Have You tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sorry...my second example was a wrong one. If it 3.98, expected output would be 1.3,1.3 and 1.38

Comment: Is it safe to assume you want a max of 2 decimal places?

Comment: as Janes suggested, I can go for 3.99/2 which is equal to 1.995. But as the data produced by our system needs to feed to other system where they will round up the value. In such case there are chances of loosing values.

Comment: @Naresh Why not `1.32, 1.32, 1.33`?

Comment: @Rawling, that is the optimized expected outout.

Comment: @JonB yes max of 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Naresh, what are the requirements of the 'optimized expected output'?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly good question, it just wasn't expressed very clearly. I think what Naresh wants to do is similar to splitting the bill at a restaurant. You want to split the value evenly, but cannot charge a value less than 0.01 -- so in some cases, one person gets charged 0.01 more/less than everyone else.

Comment: @JonB That's what I'd have assumed, but a couple of the examples given don't fit.

Comment: @Naresh You examples are much clearer now, but your `3.95` and `3.98` examples are inconsistent - for one you have `x, x, x+0.02` and for the other you have `x, x+0.01, x+0.01`. Is there a reason these are treated differently e.g. you prefer "even" numbers?

Comment: @Rawling, there is no such preference. I have updated expected output for 3.98. For 3.95, I think it is the closest equal combination with out loosing any value.

Comment: @Naresh That looks consistent to me, you've got my reopen vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested with your supplied values. May need some tweaking:

```
static IEnumerable<decimal> SplitValue2(decimal value, int count)
{
    if (count <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("count must be greater than zero.", "count");
    var result = new decimal[count];

    decimal runningTotal = 0M;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var remainder = value - runningTotal;
        var share = remainder > 0M ? Math.Max(Math.Round(remainder / ((decimal)(count - i)), 2), .01M) : 0M;
        result[i] = share;
        runningTotal += share;
    }

    if (runningTotal < value) result[count - 1] += value - runningTotal;

    return result;
}
```

This assumes you pass in a value with 2 decimal precision. If you pass in 3.999, you're not going to get correct results.

Comment: If you want you can use `(decimal.GetBits(value)[3] >> 16) % 256` to get the number of decimal places specified in the input decimal.

Comment: This doesn't work for `count` > 3; e.g. `0.03` split between `5` gives `.01 .01 .01 .01 -.01` not `.01 .01 .01 0 0`.

Comment: @Rawling good catch. It's a bit of an edge case, but I can fix it.

Comment: Do it quick, because I'm posting my own version if this gets reopened :p

Comment: Maybe the negative part was a poor example; this still saves all the "difference" for the last number, e.g. `(1.03M, 5)` gives `.21 .21 .21 .21 .19` rather than `.21 .21 .21 .20 .20`.

Comment: @JonB, I will be always passing values with 2 decimals or less.

Comment: @JonB, it's working very well. Thanks for your reply. But as Rawling said, for 1.03M it is not a closest output.

Comment: Tried you updated answer, it'a working very well. Thanks Jon. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is intending to split in rounded numbers using an extension method, It ca be done so by doing the below. Eg. split 25 into 4 would give a result like 6,6,6,7. Thanks @ Jon B

```
 public static IEnumerable<int> PartitionMeInto(this int value, int count)
    {
        if (count <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("count must be greater than zero.", "count");
        var result = new int[count];

        int runningTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var remainder = value - runningTotal;
            var share = remainder > 0 ? remainder / (count - i) : 0;
            result[i] = share;
            runningTotal += share;
        }

        if (runningTotal < value) result[count - 1] += value - runningTotal;

        return result;
    }
```

Usage

```
        int value = 25;

        var result = value.PartitionMeInto(4);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a requirement in which a number for ex: 29 is divided into a constant arrays and the remainder has to be appended at the last.

29= 9,9,9,3. for this my code is.

```
       List<int> split(int num,int splitBy)
           {

               List<int> r = new List<int>();
               int v = Convert.ToInt32(num / splitBy);
               r.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(splitBy, v).ToArray());
               var remaining = num % splitBy;
               if (remaining != 0)
                   r.Add(remaining);
               return r;

           }
```

Happy coding!!!